# How to properly resize image for Chat bubble in swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, chat

I triend cap insets but I can't set it properly. Please guide me or update me with code to do this.

I am attaching the image here which I want to resize as a chat bubble in Swift 4

[image: Chat bubble image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Asset Catalog Slicing: https://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know

Comment: Do you want to set bubble's height with it's content height (label text etc.)?

Comment: Yes. I want to properly resize image size based on it's content. @Emre Ciftci

Comment: Another approach to consider is to use a shape layer and draw the image. It's simple enough to be pretty trivial to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create a view and set image in the view with leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints.

   2. And then put the label in the view -same hierarchy with image-, you should set label's leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to view (not to imageView) for intrinsicContentSize. And set label's `numberOfLines = 0`.

PS: Do not set static height for label or imageView, it'll break intrinsicContentSize.

[image]

Comment: image will stretch and will not look good if smaller or bigger. I want image scalling looks same if it gets smaller or bigger.

Comment: Mmmm. You can create bubble with custom view. Not an image. I think this custom bubble view works for you. Because the way you said the imageView's width and height increase same ratio.